# How to use icons instead of buttons for ng2smart table

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, ng2-smart-table

I am using ng2 smart table and I want to use icons instead of buttons for AddNew row,edit,delete,update,create,cancel buttons.Also I wantto make one of the columns in my table as checkbox and I am not sure how to do that.Please someone suggest me a solution as early as possible.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: I tried to use nebular icons and installed all packages required but still I am getting errors while building and build is failing

Comment: please provide stackblitz

Comment: I followed this link https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/register-icon-pack#register-icon-pack

Answer (score 2):

you can just use icon tags instead of text in ButtonContent of table settings

```
settings = {
    delete: {
      confirmDelete: true,

      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:32px"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: 'save',
      cancelButtonContent: 'cancel',

    },
    add: {
      confirmCreate: true,
      addButtonContent:'<i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:32px"></i>'
    },
    edit: {
      confirmSave: true,
      editButtonContent:'<i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:32px"></i>'
    },
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID',
      },
      name: {
        title: 'Full Name',
      },
      username: {
        title: 'User Name',
      },
      email: {
        title: 'Email',
      },
    },
  };
```

[Click here to view example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table-rachgx)

Comment: Do i have to install any libraries for these icons?

Comment: you just need to include this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: I included the stylesheet mentioned and settings as above,but I didnt see any change on my screen

Comment: @LakshmivyshnaviMahankali how did you included the stylesheet ?

Comment: I added this line of code in my index.html    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Comment: All icons are displaying but the Add New(+) is not showing on screen.I tried putting edit and trash icons in place of addNewButtonContent,even they were not showing.But if I use  plus icon at other place  like this                                    delete: {
     confirmDelete: true,
     deleteButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
    },                                                      it is showing up on screen. What i mean is whichever icon is kept in place of Add new its not showing up on screen

Comment: this.settings = {
     add: {
        confirmCreate: true,
          addButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',
          createButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-save"></i>',
          cancelButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>'
          },
  delete: {
      confirmDelete: true,
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>'
  },
  edit: {
    confirmSave: true,
    editButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>',
    saveButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-save"></i>',
     cancelButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>'
                }}